# exchanges with different units in brightway

Tags: brightway

is it possible in Brightway to define an activity with exchanges with different units ? 
(e.g. terajoule instead of megajoule). I wrote a little code to test this and my naive approach does not seem to work:

```
co2_f=[f for f in bw.Database('biosphere3')
if 'Carbon dioxide' in f['name']
and ' fossil' in f['name']
and f['categories']==('air', 'low population density, long-term')
][0]
co2_f

for act in bw.Database('ei_35cutoff'):
    if act['unit']=='megajoule':
       break

db = bw.Database("a&e")

db.write({
("a&e", "cat1"): 
    {
    'name': 'cat1',
    'unit': 'kilogram',
    'exchanges': [
        {'input': act.key  ,'amount': 10,'type': 'technosphere','unit':'megajoule'},
        {'input': co2_f.key,'amount': 1,'type': 'biosphere','unit':'kilogram'}]
    },

("a&e", "cat2"): 
    {
    'name': 'cat2',
    'unit': 'kilogram',
    'exchanges': [
        {'input': act.key  ,'amount': 10,'type': 'technosphere','unit':'terajoule'},
        {'input': co2_f.key,'amount': 1,'type': 'biosphere','unit':'kilogram'}]
    },
("a&e", "cat3"): 
    {
    'name': 'cat3',
    'unit': 'kilogram',
    'exchanges': [
        {'input': act.key  ,'amount': 10,'type': 'technosphere','unit':'megajoule'},
        {'input': co2_f.key,'amount': 1,'type': 'biosphere','unit':'ton'}]
    },
})

ipcc2013 = ('IPCC 2013', 'climate change', 'GWP 100a')

for a in db:
    actlca=bw.LCA({a:1},method=ipcc2013)
    actlca.lci()
    actlca.lcia()
    print(a['name'],actlca.score)
```

and all produce the same results. As if CO2 were kg and `act` in megajoule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "does Brightway2 scale exchanges based on the 'units' attribute", the answer is no.

Like almost everything else in Brightway2, this is not impossible. However, units are not part of the `processed` data stored by Brightway (i.e. it is not part of the stored structured arrays from which the `MatrixBuilder`s build the **A** and **B** matrices).

See [here](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/intro.html#intermediate-and-processed-data) and [here](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/lca.html#building-matrices) for more info in processed data and building matrices.